# cx_oracle TNS: Connect timeout

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, mysql-python, cx-oracle

I am trying to link to a Oracle Database using cx_Oracle in python and keep getting the error:
`DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred`

Here is the code I am running:

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*ip*)(PORT=*port*))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=*service_name*)))'
db= cx_Oracle.connect('*username*', '*password*', dsn_tns, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: can you ping the database from command line `tnsping net_service_name count`?

Comment: kinda. I get successfully identify the alias but get a time-out error.

`Used parameter files:
C:\ProgramFiles\product\12.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out`